# Open iTunes links in Web Browser

Tags: itunes, windows, itunes-store, web-browser

On Google Chrome running on Windows 10, is it possible to open iTunes links in the browser rather than trying to open the iTunes desktop client? I don't want to start this heavyweight software for the purpose of viewing apps, given that with play.google.com the equivalent for Android works perfectly fine without a desktop client.

It seems to affect only `/de/` links, e.g. [this /de/ link](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/warren-buffetts-paper-wizard/id1461432935?mt=8) tries to redirect to the desktop client, while [the /us/ version](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/warren-buffetts-paper-wizard/id1461432935?mt=8) does not.

It also doesn't occur consistently for all links. For instance, for the Steam Link app, both the [/us/](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/steam-link/id1246969117) and [/de/](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/steam-link/id1246969117) links open in the browser, without trying to redirect to the desktop client.

[image: message]

Comment: I assume you mean links that are already displayed on a web page(?) If I click on an app link on a web page it is a regular old everyday hypertext link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/[etc.] and opens fine in Firefox for the PC on a PC with Win 10. It might be helpful if you give at least one detailed example of a link you click on that *doesn't* open in a web browser. Note also that the only way to actually install an app via your PC or Mac is to actually have iTunes or download it directly on your iOS device.

Comment: @SteveChambers Added clarification. It seems to occur only for /de/ links.

Comment: Apparently a redirect to the Desktop client is attempted when the app in question is not available in the region mentioned in the URL (`/de` in your case). That explains the inconsistency in the behavior.